# Code using wrong namespace

Tags: c#, sql, namespaces

I having an aspx.cs file that I am adding code to. I have all the right namespaces and references in my solution, but my code is referencing the wrong namespace with the following error on my `Server server = new Server()`

> System.Web.UI is a 'property' but used as a 'type'

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace IISLoggingSolution
{
    public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //connection string for SQL DB
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=Computer\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IISLogs;Integrated Security=True";

            //Location of the query to be ran
            string script = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\query.txt");

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            //this is the error line
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

            //executes query
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);


        }
    }
}
```

How can I get it to use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo instead of trying to used the System.Web.UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using NS_Server = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.Web.UI;

...

NS_Server.Server server = new NS_Server.Server();
```

the line using NS_Server is an alias. You can use it as a shortcut when there are namespace collisions.

Comment: I did not know you could give alias to namespaces, this could prove beneficial in the future. Thanks!

Comment: np! glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias directive:

using Server = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management...Server;

It may not work if property takes precedence, but in that cas you can simply specify the full namespade path.

```
var server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management....Server();
```